# Camel Netty UDP listener listening on 0.0.0.0 and not receiving packets

Tags: java, udp, netty, apache-camel

I'm new to Camel, Netty and UDP, but I've been researching this for a while and still can't figure out what's going on.

All I'm trying to do is implement a UDP listener using Camel and Netty (currently on Windows 7, but will be moving the project to Linux). My spring config is as follows:

```
<camel:camelContext id="test">
    <camel:route>
        <camel:from uri="netty:udp://localhost:5150?sync=false"/>
        <camel:to uri="log:cameltest?level=DEBUG"/>     
        <camel:to uri="file://outbox"/>
    </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

The listener appears to starts fine (running through Eclipse). However, when I do a netstat, I see this:

```
UDP    0.0.0.0:5150
UDP    [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:5150
```

when I am expecting it to be listening on 127.0.0.1. Nothing I've read online is clear on if this is expected behavior for Camel/Netty/UDP.

I'm testing this by sending from a Java NIO UDP Client. If an NIO UDP Server is listening, it receives the packet fine (all done through localhost).

I also tested a Camel/Netty/TCP listener and that works fine.

Why is the listener listening to all local addresses? And if so, why isn't it receiving my packet from localhost?

Comment: I would add a logging handler and log out all the channel events.

Comment: I've debugged as far as I could go, all the way up to the native `bind0` method in `sun.nio.ch.Net`. I didn't see anything unusual, and no exceptions were thrown. It looks like no matter what hostname I specify, it still tries to listen on all local addresses. I just tried to make my NIO UDP Server listen at 0.0.0.0, and it receives packets from my NIO client just fine. Still don't know why the camel version isn't...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out. This was my final spring context:

```
<bean class="org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.string.StringDecoder" id="stringDecoder">
    <constructor-arg value="ISO_8859_1" />
</bean>

<camel:camelContext id="test">
    <camel:route>
        <camel:from uri="netty:udp://localhost:5150?decoder=#stringDecoder&amp;disconnectOnNoReply=false&amp;sync=false"/>
        <camel:to uri="log:cameltest?level=DEBUG"/>     
        <camel:to uri="file://outbox"/>
    </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

After doing some research on UDP and Netty, I found out that listening on 0.0.0.0:[port#] seemed to be the default behavior for Netty/UDP. For more information on what 0.0.0.0 means, [see this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1).

A fellow programmer suggested (because I'm essentially working with a framework within a framework), to take out the camel stuff and try to get it working in Netty. I tried this and I was able to get it working, and was also able to send to it from my NIO UDP Client. For a while I thought the problem was in camel because I couldn't see anything wrong with the Netty implementation.

After hours of step-by-step debugging in the Netty/UDP, Camel/TCP, and the "broken" Camel/UDP, I noticed that the Camel Netty implementation used a `ConnectionlessBootstrap` from the `org.jboss` package to bind the connection. In my Netty implementation, I was using `Bootstrap` from the `io.netty` package.

I found an example using the `ConnectionlessBootstrap` and `org.jboss` package from http://massapi.com/class/org/jboss/netty/bootstrap/ConnectionlessBootstrap.java.html. When I got it working, I compared the implementation to mine, and noticed he had an encoder and decoder on both ends. This is where I got the idea to add a `CharsetUtil.ISO_8859_1` decoder to my listener and managed to get the project working.

I also noticed I was only able to send to it once at a time. Setting the property `disconnectOnNoReply` to false allowed the listener to receive multiple times without disconnecting.

Hope this helps someone out in the future. :)

[edit] Actually after further testing, the "disconnectOnNoReply" may not be needed. I just tried it without it and it works.